# PHP mail() is sending out old emails

Tags: php, email

I was using this when a form was submitted:

```
foreach ($_GET as $field=>$value){
    $body.=$field.': '.$value."\n";
}
mail ('me@my-job.com, coworkers@my-job.com','submitted form',$body,"From: from<me@my-job.com>\n");
```

So someone is trying to hack us and they've been submitting the form with various suspicious fields. I had it append the IP

```
$body.='IP:'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
```

& then saw that they were all coming from the same IP and banned it.

The **problem** is that I'm still getting old emails delivered to me. `Gmail` says that they are 5 hours old but they are just showing up to me now.

Is there an outgoing mail queue in `PHP` where they're somehow being throttled and that's why I'm still getting them now or is something else happening?

Comment: Check the headers - each `Received` header will add the server the mail passed through, and a timestamp. It's possible that if there was a flood of mails, an intermediate server decided to start rate limiting them. You can also check to make sure that these are indeed older emails.

Comment: quite simply your mail server isn't trusted, as such lots of emails will be delayed and will also likely end up in a spam folder. this can be mitigated by using SPF and/or DKIM DNS records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the PHP `mail` command, by default it contacts the destination (Google in your case), and passes the message forward.

Unless you have an intermediate mail server set-up, what's most likely happening in your case is that Google has queued up all your emails, and is slowly delivering them to your inbox. You will simply need to wait it out.

Comment: Oh that makes more sense than what I'd thought. Thank you.